# "Mask" LeafletJS Map with Clip-Path

Tags: html, css, leaflet

I have a LeafletJS map, which is centered on 2 markers, an origin and a destination, on the bottom page of a document. In other words, the document has an implicit height of 200%.

What I am trying to do is create a page transition so that the map appears initially card-like (i.e. a rectangle with rounded corners that is slightly smaller than full screen) and then transforms to full screen as the bottom page is scrolled to the top.

The problem with my initial attempt was that, if the `width` or `height` of the `#map` is directly or indirectly changed, the map "pans" off center.

Therefore, here is the solution that I devised:

- `#map` element or container always has a `100%` `width` and `height` that is equal to `html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 }`
- instead of resizing the map or another container, create a mask, overlay it on top of the `#map` element, and manipulate the mask so that the `#map` never changes its size (and requires "panning"), yet `#map` appears to expand as the mask "border" shrinks

However, I have not coded in a while, so I am having a little trouble implementing this. I suspect something like `#map { clip-path: polygon()` or `path() }` may be the most elegant way to achieve this, but I have no clue how to create even an approximation of the shape, which I will include below, **that is responsive to viewport size.**

[image]

Can anybody shed some light on this?

## I found my answer:

## `clip-path: inset(24px round 24px)`